# How to get a fixed number of evenly spaced points describing a path?

Tags: algorithm, math, path, point

Given is a path described by an ordered array of points (x,y). I'm looking for an algorithm that describes this path with a given number of points (k) that are evenly spaced along the path.

**Input points**:

```
[[x1,y1], ..., [xn,yn]] (randomly spaced)
```

Where *x1,y1* is the first waypoint and *xn,yn* the last. The path is defined by connecting every point to the next with a straight line.

```
(Xn,Yn) -----> (Xn+1,Yn+1)
```

**Expected output**:

```
[[x1,y1], ..., [xk,yk]] (evenly spaced)
```

[Image of an example path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhGDr.png)

**Update:** I've looked at Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm. It will reduce the number of points but it won't allow to set a fixed number of points and they are not evenly spaced.

Comment: @wim any idea how to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by "describing" the path? You have N pairs of (x,y) values as your **input**, and what do you want to have as the **output**?

Comment: sorry, i've just understood your question. But the path with EVENLY spaced points will not be the same as the INITIAL path. It will modify it.

Comment: I disagree with the close reason consensus. This question does NOT ask for a tool, but for an algoritm. It *is*, however, close-worthy, as expected output is not stated and it is therefore unclear.

Comment: @Xan How is the expected output not stated? "a given number of points that are evenly spaced" isn't this the expected output?

Comment: Where exactly is the question asking to "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource". The question is about finding a algorithm that solves a specific programming problem. How can the question be improved to make this more clear?

Comment: Okay, output "number of points that are evenly spaced", got that. But then it's unclear what the _path is_. There are infinitely many paths that go through a finite set of points.

Comment: Also, does "evenly spaced" means "evenly spaced along the path"?

Comment: @Xan Please have a look at the sample image of a path I've linked to. I'm not able to attach it here since I'm having too few credits.

Comment: It's not a [_path_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)), it's a discrete set of points. There are still infinitely many paths that fit the points.

Comment: @Xan: Thanks for your input. I have added your remakrs to the question. But how likely is it that the question gets opened again?

Comment: I would vote against. It's still an ill-defined problem.

Comment: @Xan: So it's not clear to you what I meant with path?

Comment: @Xan: So it's better to close a question than to help improve it?

Comment: I am helping, by trying to explain what's wrong with it. You don't get it yet. Like I said, there is no such thing as "**the** path described by a set of points". There are infinitely many paths that _just_ cross a set of points. You need to describe how you pick _one_ of such paths, perhaps by requiring additional properties. This is exactly what @Ivaylo's answer meant.

Comment: @Xan: Thanks for explaining. I have update the question. Is it now more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you have a list of points to turn into a path, you want to make the path to have some smoothness to it. There are techniques to do that, but they make the second part of your problem more difficult to solve.

You mention in a comment that a straight line connecting each input point would be considered acceptable, which leads to an easy solution.

Calculate the distance between consecutive input points. Add up all those distances. Divide the total by the number of output points you desire; this is the output point spacing.

Now go through the list of input points and sum the distance traveled so far. If that distance goes beyond the next output distance you require, use linear interpolation between that point and the previous point to determine the output point.

Note: the output points will be equidistant when measured against the original input path, but they will not necessarily be equal distance from each other. Changing the number of points in this case *changes the path*.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to interpolate the path, as the with the initial discrete input you will not be able to solve the problem. That is you will need to "guess" how the path will go between the input points. This guess(called interpolation) may not be accurate, but your task is to get as close to the real path as possible. There are many ways in which you can do that for instance you can use [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) or some polynomial interpolation.

Once you've done that you will have a continuous path - that is a path that can be described with f(x) where x goes from 0 to the length of the path and f(x) returns a point in the plane. With this function, the points you are interested in will be `f((i * L) / M)`. Here `L` is the length of the path, `M` is the number of evenly spaced points you are interested in and i goes through the values `0,1,2,...M-1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you provide some kind of pseudocode to make your solution more clear?

Comment: @Marlon it is not a complete solution it simply gives pointers. Path interpolation is a huge field and I can not possibly know which is the best algorithm for your specific case.

Comment: @Marlon, Ivaylo is right, you really have two problems in one. First is to turn your list of points to a path, second is to turn the path into another list of points. Both problems are non-trivial.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for you input. But isn't the path defined by the order of the points in the array?

Comment: @Marlon no it is not. Consider the 4 points of a square - if you didn't know it was a square, they could also make a circle. Two paths possible from the same list of 4 points, and many more possibilities besides.

Comment: Excuse the hasty Paint, but no, path is not defined by a finite set of points on it: [example](http://imgur.com/L6qINjz) So even with your edit, your question is not a well-defined math problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks again. Why is it important if it's an square or an circle? What do I have to define to make the question valid?

Comment: @Xan: Thanks again. So when I define that every way point is connected to the next one with a straight line, will it make the problem well-defined?

Comment: Yes, that's a unique path. But please note that if you construct the same piecewise-linear path through your output, it will be potentially a vastly different path.

Comment: @Xan Well, I have update the question again to represent your hints. Thanks. I'm aware of that problem. Any input on how such an algorithm could work?

Comment: Well, your question is now fixed, reopened, and has a correct answer. Congratulations on getting it back on track.